# PHP echo a certain position from multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I've got multiple arrays.  From each array, I need to echo the position '0'. How do I do this?

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [accountname] => test
        [0] => test
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [accountname] => test2
        [0] => test2
    )
```

I've tried this, but it echoes all the positions from the array which are 0, not the position 0 inside the array.

Now it echoes `test, test`,  but I need `test,test2`.

Comment: You forgot to add your current code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

use array_walk or foreach to traverse your array, use the index 0 to access the inner array.

```
array_walk($array, function($v){echo $v[0];});
```

Answer (score 1):

Many possible approaches. Take a look at this simple example for some of them:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [
        'accountname' => 'test',
        0 => 'test'
    ],
    [
        'accountname' => 'test2',
        0 => 'test2'
    ]
];

// #1: treating the input as a table and selecting a "column": 
var_dump(array_column($input, 0));

// #2: using an anonymous "lambda" function: 
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($val) use (&$output) { $output[]=$val[0]; });
var_dump($output);

// #3: destructive approach flattening the input:
$output = $input;
array_walk($output, function(&$val) { $val = $val[0]; });
var_dump($output);

// #4: simple "foreach" loop, traditional approach: 
$output = [];
foreach($input as $entry) {
    $output[] = $entry[0];
}
var_dump($output);

// #5: classical "for" loop, scales better for big data:
$output = [];
for($i=0; $i<count($input); $i++) {
    $output[] = $input[$i][0];
}
var_dump($output);
```

The output of each obviously is:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "test"
  [1] =>
  string(5) "test2"
}
```